# simple login application with parse.jar gives 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.ParseUser'

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am working on a simple login android application in android studio with parse. Just a few backs I switched in to studioo from ecclipse so I am not much familier with that. I am refering the following tutorial.[parse tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-login-and-signup-tutorial/)

I have done everything as they mentioned. Added parse.jar[add in to libs folder and settings file updated ] and update app gradile file. 
But when I tried to run the application , it crashes.`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.ParseUser`.

If anybody have any idea about my issue please help me to solve it. I didn't find any similar questions thats why posting.

My app gradile file have below lines.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
```

} and we can't add dependencies to outer [main] gradile file..right?...there is

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Comment: show the code what you have done??

Comment: you want the entire code or my gradile code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a compile command to your `build.gradle` file?
For example:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```